# Unwrapping an Optional value on callback function swift

Tags: swift, callback, option-type

I made this question because even though there are multiple ones with similar titles I was not able to find one with the same issue I have. I have a function that calls on a function that has a call back. This second function makes another call to another function that has a callback. My issue is, the third function that is being called is inside a .m file which through a bridge I am able to access it. This function returns nil if there is no error. The problem is that I am unable to allow nil in the callback function and it return the error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I am new to swift and from what I have read using optionals is a good way but it still giving issues. Any ideas?

Code:

mainViewController.swift

```
func makeACall(){
   var service:Service!
   service = Service()

   // error happens on this next line I believe is the error variable
   service.lookup(item: itemTextField.text, callback: { (details:String?, error: serviceError?) -> Void in

   if (error != nil){
    //do something
   }

   })
}
```

Service.swift

```
func lookup(item:String!, callback: (_ details:String?, _ error: serviceError?) -> Void){

super.fetchItem(item, callback: { (details:String?, error: serviceError?) -> Void in 
     callback(details, error!)

 }) // in objective C .m file fetchItem returns the call back as callback(details, nil) if no error

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your callback has a optional, why are you force-unwrapping it?

You didn't for details.

Both of these are optionals, yet you force unwrapped the error one. Use callback like this:

```
callback(details, error)
```

As for the text going in. Just do this before the fetch:

```
guard let itemText = itemTextField.text else { return }
```

Or if you want to call the function even with an empty string you can do this

```
let itemText = itemTextField.text ?? ""
```

And then use itemText like so:

```
service.lookup(item: itemText, callback: { (details:String?, error: serviceError?) -> Void in
     if (error != nil){
     //do something
     }
})
```

Comment: thank you or your help! I tried what you recommended but unfortunately the error still happens, also on the service func, would you recommend adding func lookup(item:String!, callback: escaping keyword on the function line?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 
 - This error means that a value was nil, where you used a bang(!) to unwrap it. Try to avoid them. I also don't get why you declared your var service: Service! like you did. why not just directly initialize it?
Yes definetly add @escaping if you are using swift 3 you need it. I just presumed you aren't since your code didn't have it. EDIT: To be clear -  Your crash cannot happen if you stop using bangs(!).